# How many people were in an average Iron Age Celtic settlement?

Tags: population, celts, iron-age

How many people were in an average Celtic settlement (or tribe - not sure if they correspond as one to one) in the Iron Age?

My intuitive estimation is "from 100 to 5000".

I know the Iron Age is long enough but information on any time range would be nice.

Comment: Some evidence of research would be nice. Where have you looked?

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. What has your research shown you so far? Where have you already searched? What did you find? Please help us to help you. You might find it helpful to review the [site tour](https://history.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://history.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [ask].

Comment: @sempaiscuba Question about a fact not technology variations could only be polluted with details of my research but not clarified.

Comment: @LarsBosteen I've looked in Internet with Google (in 1.5 languages - Russian and "technichal" English) and found nothing reliable. My intuitive estimation is "from 100 to 5000". But it does not add anything useful to my question.

Comment: I searched "iron age celtic settlement" with duckduckgo and got oppidum a page down after some references to iron age and medieval Britons. If you don't know that "oppidum" is what you're looking for that is misleading, imo.

Comment: @SerG - welcome to the site and thanks for asking an interesting question.  Please don't reply in comments, but edit your question to address the issues raise.  Like most SE sites, there is an implicit expectation that questions should contain preliminary research; nobody is being hostile, but it the questions matter to the way we do history here.  Hope you get a good answer.

Comment: @Mark C. Wallace♦ I'm not sure how exactly your edit makes question better for googling or reader perception. I really used phrases like "tribe **population size**" in my search. And I really hate questions that overfilled with useless details on stackexchange. At least simple googling (without result) is not experimental research that should be referenced.

Comment: I was trying to be helpful based on years of experience. Questions where OP [replies in comments](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3915/1401) get more downvotes, get closed faster, and get poorer answers.  Simply  put, the question should contain evidence of prior  research and should contain all the information needed to research the question.  This is [not](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3224) [uncommon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title/10648#10648) across SE. It shows courtesy for people who are doing the research.

Comment: @SerG The start of the Iron Age can be between 1200BCE & 500BCE, depending on where in Europe you are talking about. The "[Celts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celts)" (as in speakers of one of the Celtic languages) eventually had a geographic spread that covered most of Europe.  If we know what & where you are researching, we _might_ be able to give a meaningful answer to your question (although I suspect in almost all cases that answer is going to be something like "_we really don't know, and here's why_ ...").  That is why evidence of your prior research is important.

Comment: That would be correct if the question was about Urnfield or early Hallstatt times. But we found out that it is about the late iron age oppida civilisation. Sure, any question and answer can be made better, more encompassing, more focussing on special cases, latest research. I can imagine that you guys asking about upper paleolithic stone tool industries could equally provoke remarks. Or me asking about WWII ... ;-)

Comment: @ebv So, late Iron Age oppida, but _where_?  Oppida are found from Britain to the Hungarian plains and as far south as Spain. Their size varies enormously, and we don't fully understand their function.  There is a reason why "_This question does not show any research effort_" is an **explicit** reason for downvoting questions.

Comment: @sempaiscuba so what is the range of square and time I may ask about in one question?

Comment: @SerG Our [Help Centre](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) has some advice on scope of questions.  In general, share your research & tell us exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: In this case, the accepted answer is wrong about what archaeologists mean when they talk of "Celts", and basically wrong about settlement size unless you are just asking about oppida in the late Iron Age (and even then the range of sizes varies enormously depending on _where_ you're asking about). For Iron Age settlements in general, the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oppidum) is correct when it states "_the vast majority of settlements in the Iron Age were small, with perhaps no more than 50 inhabitants_".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: thousands.

For that, we must define "celtic". All modern folklore aside, fom a mere archeological point of view "[celts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celts)" were the [oppida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oppidum) building people, referred to as "Keltoi" by the Greek ~500BC. Archeologists usually mean the late pre-Roman iron age people when they speak of "Celts" in general, with the eponymous find site being [La Tène](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_T%C3%A8ne_culture) in Lake Neuchâtel. Though we don't say "culture", rather "time" or "period" because culture has a different meaning for different people. La-Tène time spans ~400 years (~450BC until Romans).

But that definition is not allways followed strictly. Often times, Hallstatt (early Iron Age in Europe) is included in "celtic" times.

Some of the best researched oppida are Bibracte (up to 30,000 inhabitants when the Romans made their debut).

http://www.bibracte.fr/
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bibracte

and Manching.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oppidum_of_Manching (maybe 10,000 inhabitants)

and a list of many more can easily be found when searching "Oppidum". Some of them were surrounded by really huge earth works or situated on spurs in the landscape, fortified by "[Murus Gallicus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murus_Gallicus)", a terminus technicus coined by J. C.

Sorry for all the Wikipedia, hope the contents aren't that far from archaeological evidence. Can provide more info when necessary.

A note on sources:
It is not trivial to find something in English and iron age is not my specialty, but I found a recent [paper](https://www.academia.edu/3885363/Moore_Braun_Creighton_et_al..._2013_Oppida_Agglomerations_and_Suburbia_the_Bibracte_Environs_and_New_Perspectives_on_Late_Iron_Age_Urbanism_in_Central-Eastern_France) on other types of settlement (not enclosed as the oppida) around late La Tène and in the orbit of Bibracte, for the archeologically interested. (Sure, an iron age guru could easily link to more information on the matter). It is better than the Wikipedia stuff, which serves as a rough outline at best.

Comment: Yes, I really was interested in "La Tene culture" and I had found some info about oppidums but not specifically about population. And also I was in doubt about oppid's averageness (may be it's like a capital or administration).

Comment: The function is not clearly known. Some of them were large enough to hold their inhabitants + farmland + animals. When searching further, take with a shovel of salt anything that refers to religion or social stratification because that is mostly speculation. Prehistory has nothing but material remains, soil, stratea, isotopes, pollen, bones, varves, tree rings, ... that sort of things :-)

Comment: Actually, most archaeologists I know avoid using the term "Celt", except to mean a person who spoke one of the Celtic languages.  The geographic and temporal ranges are just too large for the term to be meaningful beyond that.  As for the size of settlements, the truth is that we have no idea.  Oppida are found from Britain to the Hungarian plains and as far south as Spain.  Their size varies enormously, and we don't fully understand their function. The fact the Caesar used the term means he thought of some as "settlements", but that's about it.

Comment: Other way round. We don't really know in what relation these groups all stood and what language(s) they spoke. Some things can be inferred or "suspected" How could we know, it is gone. But we do know some of their settlements, arrangements inside and outside of the places, craftmenship, trade and relation to the surrounding or even far away places. Part of their material culture came upon us, that's why.

Comment: We certainly don't know what percentage of the population actually lived in those oppida, and we know very little about settlements outside the oppida.

Comment: @ebv Actually, the [Wikipedia article on the Celts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celts#Archaeological_evidence) puts it rather well: "... _archaeologists have repeatedly concluded that language, material culture, and political affiliation do not necessarily run parallel_."  That is exactly why the term "_Celts_" has no meaning beyond a "_group of people that spoke the same family of languages_", and why we generally try very hard not to talk about "Celts" if we can possibly avoid it. It is certainly not a synonym for the people of the late pre-Roman Iron Age.

Comment: I need archaeological evidence for that one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104211/discussion-between-ebv-and-sempaiscuba).

Comment: Thanks, @KorvinStarmast, for the corrections :-)

Comment: Thank you for a nice answer and particularly the link to Bibracte.  Fascinating read there.